# How dynamically edit field in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to change editable property of the field, but this way it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
function changeDescription(rawGrid, isEditableDescription) {
        var grid = rawGrid.data("kendoGrid");
        if (!grid) return;

        if (isEditableDescription) {
            grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields["Description"].editable = true;
        }
        else {
            grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields["Description"].editable = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the setOptions method of the grid: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions

```js
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
var options = grid.getOptions();
var editable = !options.columns[0].editable || options.columns[0].editable();
options.columns[0].editable = function() { return !editable; };
grid.setOptions(options);
```

Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/APEBuhaN

Comment: is there a way to do that without grid.setOptions?  When I use it I get 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeClass')

Comment: @Aska - unfortunately I don't think there is. Kendo doesn't expose changing any one of the options individually.